# How to do any in XSD?

Tags: xsd

I have a question about XSD?

In dtd, we can use any to not restrict the element type and tag like

```
<!ELEMENT question ANY>
<question>
  <q1>question 1</q1>
</question>
```

Is there a way to do it in XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow *any elements* inside question you can use `<xs:any>` which represents *any* element:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="question">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The attribute `processContents="skip"` is used to inform the parser to skip validation of the child elements. You might want to use `lax` instead of `skip` if you are including tags that *might* be validated if a schema is available, such as XHTML tags. The value `strict` requires that the tags that eventually are used in your instance be declared in a Schema.

If you also want to allow text to appear outside elements such as in:

```
<question>
  <q1>question 1</q1>
  some text
</question>
```

Then add `mixed="true"` as an attribute to `<complexType>`.